# Granting permission/ deleting files which need admin permission

Tags: c++, file-permissions, permission-denied, delete-operator

I have recently started coding C++ and I am wondering how I can delete a file/grant user sufficient permission to delete a file. For instance, deleting a windows file.(Wanting to know for educational purposes)

I have tried DeleteFile() and std::remove, but whenever running such code, all I get is "Access denied". Is there any (easy) ways to force delete such files even though my account is classified as "Administrator"?

```
DeleteFile("filepath");
std::remove("filepath");
```

Code meant for windows 7 and upwards

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.

Comment: No OS specified, no sample code..

Comment: Edited @Oscar Take a look